# Pattern.compile() throws exception

Tags: java, android, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am using a regex to find if a string is present in a book page. Below is the code for the same.

```
    String regex = ".*\\b.{0}" + searchText + ".{0}.*\\b";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    pattern.matcher("This is the text area where I am trying to look for the particular text, which is in the variable searchText. This text will have the string (222M) as part of this string. The find method should give me a true result even if I don't enter the closing brakect of the word. This is a multiline string").find()
```

Observations:

- Case 1: when searchText = "(222M)"
- Result: The string is found.
- Case 2: when searchText = "(222M" // bracket missing

  I get the below exception.

  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regexp pattern near index 22:
  .*\b.{0}(1110r.{0}.*\b

Also is there a better option of finding the string in the page. Using String.contains() was inconsistent. This is on android platform.
                      ^

Comment: Note that you can remove `.{0}` that is useless since it matches an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try quoting the `searchText` `String`:

```
... + Pattern.quote(searchText) + ...
```

... as it might contain `Pattern` reserved characters, thus breaking your `Pattern`.

**Edit** ... which is the case when it contains a non-closed parenthesis.

**Edit (II)**

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish with the `".*\\b.{0}"` parts of your `Pattern`.

Here are two working example in that case:

- for literal matching (`String.contains` should perform the same)
- for non-word-bounded matching, wherein any character preceding or following the given `String` is a non-word character

  ```
  String searchText = "(222M";
  String regex = Pattern.quote(searchText);
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Pattern boundedPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)" + regex + "(?=\\W)");
  String input = "This is the text area where I am trying " +
      "to look for the particular text, which is in the variable searchText. " +
      "This text will have the string (222M) as part of this string. " +
      "The find method should give me a true result even if I don't " +
      "enter the closing brakect of the word. This is a multiline string";
  Matcher simple = pattern.matcher(input);
  Matcher bounded = boundedPattern.matcher(input);

  if (simple.find()) {
      System.out.println(simple.group());
  }
  if (bounded.find()) {
      System.out.println(bounded.group());
  }
  ```

**Output**

```
(222M
(222M
```

**Final note**

You can add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` as an initialization flag to your `Pattern`(s) if you want them to be case insensitive.

Comment: I have tried Pattern.quote(searchText), it stops the error but doesn't match the results hence defeats the purpose. The case is lowercase. And thanks for the advice on {0}.

Comment: @Zooter then your `Pattern` is not actually matching the text. You'll have to provide clear input/output examples - possibly in a new question for that.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope this helps understand the problem.

Comment: @Zooter I've had a look at your example. Of course there is no way to find the "search text", quoted or unquoted, with the `Pattern` you're using. I can show you a simpler `Pattern` if the text you're looking for is indeed the contents of `searchText`. Otherwise your second question is still unclear.

Comment: Please help me with the pattern. The problem I am facing is that when I search for "(222M" I don't get the result. The quotes are only to show that the searchText is a string so you can ignore it. Thanks for persisting and trying to help.

Comment: I tried the regex suggested by you but it doesn't solve the problem. Apologies for the late reply.