# String.contains(searchText) doesn't work for more than one word

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching, string-matching

I have some content and I am trying to find if the some "searchText" exists in the content. When I look for a single word in the "searchText", the String.contains(searchText) returns true but returns false for more than one work. Below is the snippet that shows the implementation. I need to identify if the searchText is present in the content.

```
    boolean found;
    String searchText = "particular text";
    String input = "This is the text area where I am trying " +
         "to look for the particular text, which is in the variable searchText. " +
         "This text will have the string (222M) as part of this string. " +
         "The find method should give me a true result even if I don't " +
         "enter the closing brakect of the word. This is a multiline string";
    if(input.contains(searchText)) {
        found = true;
    }
```

Do i need to use regex. 
Let me point to the research and my attempts which I didn't mention earlier.

I have already tried the following regex

`pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\W)" + searchText + "(?=\\W)");`

This too doesn't do the job.

Note: This is on Android.

Comment: That *will* return true for the case you've given, because the string contains "particular text". In other words, you've given an example where it already works - please give us an example which you'd *expect* to work, but which doesn't.

Comment: That is going to work. Also, found = input.contains(searchText)

Comment: your code return true !

Comment: This is the code that doesn't work. @Jon: If I enter text that's not in the content then it has to return false. The problem is the space in between the words "particular" and "text". It returns true if I search for particular or text. This is on android.

Comment: @Zooter: No, the space isn't a problem, because the space is in the text as well. The exact code you've given *will* detect "particular text". `String.contains` doesn't have any concept of "words" - it just looks for one sequence of characters within another.

Comment: Could it be a prob with Android then. I looked at Android and Java String class, both docs have similar description. One thing could be presence of EOL characters as the content is multi line text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pattern.compile() throws exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24325598/pattern-compile-throws-exception)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the text was multi-line. Anything that followed after the first occurrence of \n could not be found. I replaced the \n with a space and it worked.